# Dynamic margin using CSS

Tags: html, css

I am having a Tab with text and circle. I have given 9px right margin between circle and text. Now the issue is when circle size increases I need to reduce margin to 3px. Is there any I can do with CSS or do I need to write JS for it.

[image]

```
.circle {
    border-radius: 11px;
    width: 22px;
    height: 22px; 
    margin-right: 9px;
}
```

Comment: Does it need to go to exactly 3px or anywhere from 3px - 9px?

Comment: No, but should be less than 9px

Comment: I added an answer that should help if I understand correctly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on if you need it to go exactly to 3px, or anywhere between 9px and 3px, you could give your content to the right an `absolute` position. This way the content will stay put when the circle expands or decreases: [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1a9xwxjd/1/)

**Note:** The actual margins/pixels do not match the desired 3-9px margins - just an a example. Change the content in the circle to see how the gap changes.

```
.circle {
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-radius: 50%;
    margin-right: 9px;
    padding: 10px;
    height: 30px;
    line-height: 30px;
}
.rightContent {
    position: absolute;
    left: 70px;
    top: 0;
    line-height: 70px;  
}
```

Otherwise, if you do need the margin to be exactly 3px or 9px depending on the content, you will need JS.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I would definitely not use JavaScript to alter CSS in this way. I would suggest floating your text to the right using `float: right` so that the space between the circle/oval and text can be variable based on the width of the circle.